# how to search in vb.net and populate info in text boxes and combo boxes using query

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have VB.net project in which i need to search using a urno and it should populate info in all the textboxes and combo boxes that are on the form and it is the same form from which the data is stored in the database.here is the code

```
Public Class MBAUpdate
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            'Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim dbprovider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Taher\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
            Me.con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection()
            con.ConnectionString = dbprovider
            con.Open()

            Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * FROM MBA WHERE urno=" & CInt(txtb1.Text) & ";"
            Dim sqlcommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlquery, con)
            Dim ds As DataSet

            With sqlcommand
                .CommandText = sqlquery
                .Connection = con
                .ExecuteReader()
            End With

            ' MsgBox("Record Added")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

any ideas how to achieve this did quite googling did'nt help either....

Comment: Break it down. you need to start with populating your dataset with the result from the query. That is highly googleable.

Comment: i know how to fill the dataset just don't know how to populate that data in the fields....

Comment: You need to either use the data reader returned by the `ExecuteReader` method to read the returned rows yourself, or you need to create a data adapter to have it read the rows for you and populate a data set.  Which way were you attempting to go with it?  It looks like you currently have a mix of both approaches.

Comment: i open to any method just should work ....

Comment: Can you post your client-side markup?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it and its working like a charm.....

```
Public Class MBAUpdate
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            'Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim dbprovider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Taher\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
            Me.con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * FROM MBA WHERE urno=" & CInt(txtb1.Text) & ";"
            Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlquery, con)
            Dim reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
            con.ConnectionString = dbprovider
            con.Open()

            reader = command.ExecuteReader()
            reader.Read()

            txtName.Text = reader(1).ToString()
            txtFname.Text = reader(2).ToString()
            txtCAdd.Text = reader(3).ToString()
            txtPAdd.Text = reader(4).ToString()
            txtEid.Text = reader(5).ToString()
            cmbGender.Text = reader(6).ToString()
            txtMno.Text = reader(7).ToString()




            ' MsgBox("Record Added")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```